# iOS Resources/Luminaries?

Tags: ios, resources

In the .NET world, I was able to find several industry figures or luminaries' blogs to read or to follow on twitter to learn about features and trends.  Moving into the iOS realm, I'm kind of surprised how difficult it has been to find analogous resources.

What resources should I be reading/following/osmosing to get better integrated into the iOS community?

Answer (score 2):

Start at http://planetcocoa.org/, which aggregates quite a few Objective-C, Cocoa, and Cocoa Touch-related blogs.

Other good resources are:

- [Mike Ash's blog](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/)
- [Dave DeLong's blog](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/)
- [Ridiculous Fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/)
- Marcus Zarra's depressingly-titled [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/)
- Occasionally, [Wil Shipley's blog](http://blog.wilshipley.com/search/label/code)
- [Uli Kusterer's blog](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/)
- [Wolf Rentzsch's blog](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/)

There are about a million iPhone-related blogs, tutorials, etc. Don't believe everything you read, though -- there's a lot of lousy advice out there, and a lot more that's just a rehash of Apple's documentation, which is a better source in most cases. Everyone I linked above has significant credentials and something interesting to say beyond what's in the manual.

Of course, you could always just start reading the [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa), [cocoa-touch](/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch), and [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) tags here and (better) on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). And, of course, Apple has its own [developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com/).

Comment: I'd add Aaron Hillegass and Joe Conway's (amongst others) blog at Big Nerd Ranch.

http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/